# How can I append two files in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have files that look like the following:

```
File 1
------
Field A, Field B, Field C
1,2,3

aa,bb,cc

File 2
------
Field D, Field E, Field F
4,5,6

dd,ee,ff

I want to join them so the file looks like the following:

Joined File
-----------
Field A, Field B, Field C, Field D, Field E, Field F
1,2,3,4,5,6

aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff
```

So it should just skip over blank lines and append everything else to the line with a comma prefacing it. I'm doing this so I can generate "columns" in a CSV file and maintain headers. The blank lines will always match up so I don't need logic to check that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

This:
`paste -d, "file 1" "file 2" | sed -e 's/^,$//g;s/^,/,,,/g'`

Will give:

```
Field A, Field B, Field C,Field D, Field E, Field F
1,2,3,4,5,6

aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff
,,,o1,o2,o3
```

This:
`paste -d, "file 1" "file 2" | sed -e 's/^,/,,,/g;s/,$/,,,/g'`

Will give:

```
Field A, Field B, Field C,Field D, Field E, Field F
1,2,3,4,5,6
,,,,,
aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff
,,,o1,o2,o3
```

This:
`paste -d, "file 1" "file 2" | sed 's/^,$//g'`

Will give:

```
Field A, Field B, Field C,Field D, Field E, Field F
1,2,3,4,5,6

aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff
,o1,o2,o3
```

Comment: This won't work if one file has a blank line and the other has several fields. Then it will only output one comma which will throw off the output.

Comment: the question says: "The blank lines will always match up so I don't need logic to check that aspect.", so I'm not sure what you are saying.  do you want ",,,d,e,f" if lines don't match up?

Comment: What I meant to say is that if there is a blank line in file 1 there will be a corresponding blank file in file 2, but not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: gotcha, I put an solution for leaving empty line completely empty, and a solution that gives you 6 empty fields for empty lines which I think you will want.